# Refer to a pandas series value from a multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following `pandas.core.series.Series`:

```
Color
Red      4
Green    7
```

and the following multiindex dataframe. My goal is to create the `Target` column in the dataframe  through dividing `Value` by corresponding `Color` value in the `pandas.core.series.Series`. For example, first row Target should be 12/4 = 3.

```
              Value    Target
Color Animal       
Red   Tiger      12      3
      Tiger      24      6
Green Lion       21      3
      Lion       35      5
```

My following attempt works fine with single index but fails with multiindex with the  error `Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented`

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([4,7], index=['Red','Green'])
x.index.name = 'Color'

dt = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['Red','Red','Green','Green'], 'Animal': ['Tiger','Tiger','Lion','Lion'],  'Value': [12,24,21,35]})
dt.set_index(['Color','Animal'], inplace=True)
dt['Target'] = dt['Value'] / x.loc[dt.index.get_level_values('Color')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `index matching` as you have series with same labels.

```
dt['Target'] = dt.Value/x

                Value   Target
Color   Animal      
Red     Tiger   12      3.0
        Tiger   24      6.0
Green   Lion    21      3.0
        Lion    35      5.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution, this is way simpler that I imagined.